# \setstretch is reset in \begin{figure}

Tags: tables, line-spacing

I use `\setstretch{1.3}` to increase line spacing. It does increase line spacing in `tabular` environments as well, which is what I want. But if the `tabular` is in a `figure` environment, line spacing is back down to 1.

This acrticle: [baselinestretch vs. setspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/baselinestretch-vs-setspace) suggests setting `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`, but it will affect all my `tabular`s, regardless of `figure` environments.

Is there a way to force `\setstretch` for `figure` environments as well?

**EDIT:** Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.3}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can issue `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}` after `\begin{figure}`, so it will be localized there. Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)?

Comment: Thanks! But is there no solution where I can adjust line spacing for `figure` environments only once at the beginnging of the document?

Comment: That's why I asked for a minimal example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do this inside all of your `figure` environments, use `etoolbox` and its `\AtBeginEnvironment` macro

Put the following in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}}{}{}
```

Full code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{figure}{\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}}{}{}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.3}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\noindent
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! That works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

Here, I create `myfigure` environment to do what you ask.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\newenvironment{myfigure}[1][htbp]{\figure[#1]\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}}
{\endfigure}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.3}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{myfigure}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{myfigure}

\end{document}
```

However, if you wish to actually redefine the `figure` environment,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}
\let\svfigure\figure
\let\svendfigure\endfigure
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][htbp]{\svfigure[#1]\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}}
{\svendfigure}

\begin{document}
\setstretch{1.3}

\lipsum[1]

\bigskip
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{tabular}{ r | r | r }
         7168 &       1623040  &  28.30    \\
        14336 &       3228672  &  28.15    \\
        28160 &       6439936  &  28.59    \\
        56320 &      12862464  &  28.55    \\
       110592 &      25707520  &  29.06    \\
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```