# How can I space the lines in the whole document?

Tags: line-spacing

How can I space the lines in the whole  document ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! It depends on your document class which is why we need a Minimal Working Example. For the regular classes, use the `setspace` package.

Comment: Also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79046/baselinestretch-vs-setspace.