# Remove double spacing in footnotes

Tags: spacing, footnotes, sharelatex

I used the command to have double spacing in my text.

`\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2.0}`

The problem is that there is double spacing in my footnotes, too. How do I prevent double spacing in my footnotes?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) [This answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79155/106162) probably discusses what you want.

Comment: Many thanks! I couldn't find it in the "These questions may already have your answer..." section when typing my question.