# How to set different line spacing in tabular and main body?

Tags: tables, line-spacing, setspace

I want the main body to have 1.5 line spacing, while `tabular` environments should have the default (i.e. smaller) line spacing. However, the code below gives 1.5 line spacing to the whole document, including tables:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {report}
\parindent = 0cm \parskip = 0cm
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan congue leo, at 
convallis diam pulvinar nec. In venenatis neque mi, pellentesque dictum turpis ultrices 
quis. \bigskip

\centering
\begin{tabular} { p{2cm} p{6cm} }
    Hello World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce 
    accumsan congue leo, at convallis diam pulvinar nec. \\ \hline
    Goodbye World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

The answer at [tex.stackexchange.com/a/79155](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/79155) didn't work for me. In particular, I have tried replacing

- `\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}` with `\usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}`
- `\centering` with `\begin{center}`

Note: `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.8}` doesn't help because I'm concerned with the spacing between lines of text in a table, not between rows of a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that putting `tabular` inside `table` gives the default line spacing. Bernard's answer works, but I'm reluctant to import packages (i.e. `booktabs`) unnecessarily.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {report}
\parindent = 0cm \parskip = 0cm
\usepackage{setspace} \setstretch{1.5}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan congue leo, at
convallis diam pulvinar nec. In venenatis neque mi, pellentesque dictum turpis ultrices
quis.

\begin{table} [h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular} { p{2cm} p{6cm} }
    Hello World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce
    accumsan congue leo, at convallis diam pulvinar nec. \\ \hline
    Goodbye World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

A solution with `setspace`. I had to replace `\hline` with `\midrule`from `booktabs` to have some padding around the horizontal rule:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper] {report}
\parindent = 0cm \parskip = 0cm
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.5}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce accumsan congue leo, at
convallis diam pulvinar nec. In venenatis neque mi, pellentesque dictum turpis ultrices
quis. \bigskip

\begin{spacing}{0.8}\centering
\begin{tabular} { p{2cm} p{6cm} }
    Hello World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce
    accumsan congue leo, at convallis diam pulvinar nec. \\
    \midrule
    Goodbye World & Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. \\
\end{tabular}
\end{spacing}

\end{document}
```

[image]